# Single Line Checker

Tags: macros, captions, subcaption, etoolbox

I'm using `caption` and `subcaption` Packages to make more beautiful captions to my figures used in the document. So i use the following style,

```
    \DeclareCaptionStyle{MarinoCaptionStyle}{
        format=plain,
        indention=0cm,
        labelformat=simple,
        labelsep=period,
        textformat=simple,
        justification=Justified,
        font={singlespacing, MarinoFont},
        width=\textwidth,
        skip=\baselineskip,
        position=bottom,
        list=false,
        hypcap=false,
    }
```

and some way for single line, the caption wasn't automatically center, i have tried to use

```
singlelinecheck=true
```

but not worked too.

Then, i tried to create my own solution, i waste half a day searching and reading some packages documentation and using `etoolbox` i manage to get that

```
\DeclareCaptionJustification{MarinoJustification}{\ifnumequal{\the\prevgraf}{1}{\centering}{\justifying}}
```

but as well, not worked too (and yes, i called `justification=MarinoJustification`).

So i want to know if this is possible and has some solution? Or better if have a way to improve and make my solution work.

And i think this maybe could be something important to know, i use LuaLatex compiler.

Comment: The caption package doc. says: "If you specify <additional options> they get used in addition when the caption fits into a single line and this check was not disabled with the option singlelinecheck=off." So I would assume that it's sufficient to specify "justification=centering" as <additional options> parameter additionally, i.e. `\DeclareCaptionStyle{MarinoCaptionStyle}[justification=centering]{...}`

Comment: @P.M. thank you, i cannot believe it was so easy. i would like to request make a properly answer so i could accept as an answer and to clarify to me differences between the options and the additional options. Could you do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The caption package doc. says: "If you specify `<additional options>` they get used in addition when the caption fits into a single line and this check was not disabled with the option singlelinecheck=off."

As far as I have understand this part of the caption package documentation the "additional options" given in `\DeclareCaptionStyle` are applied additionally if the caption does fit into a single line., i.e. when the caption is longer than one line the regular options (given in the mandatory argument) are applied and if the caption is shorter than one line both the regular options plus the additional options (given in the optional argument) are applied.

So if shorter captions should be centered, one has to use `justification=centering` as optional argument.

Example document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption,ragged2e,graphicx,lipsum}

\DeclareCaptionFont{MarinoFont}{\itshape} % TODO

\DeclareCaptionStyle{MarinoCaptionStyle}[
        justification=centering]{
        format=plain,
        indention=0cm,
        labelformat=simple,
        labelsep=period,
        textformat=simple,
        justification=Justified,
        font={singlespacing, MarinoFont},
        width=\textwidth,
        skip=\baselineskip,
        position=bottom,
        list=false,
        hypcap=false
    }

\captionsetup{style=MarinoCaptionStyle}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics{example-image-a}
\caption{A short caption}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics{example-image-b}
\caption{\lipsum[1]}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

[image: w]

This is the code of a guessed MWE.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}

    \DeclareCaptionStyle{MarinoCaptionStyle}{
    format=plain,
    indention=0cm,
    labelformat=simple,
    labelsep=period,
    textformat=simple,
    justification=centering, %<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< changed
    font={singlespacing, it},
    width=\textwidth,
    skip=\baselineskip,
    position=bottom,
    list=false,
    hypcap=false,
}

\captionsetup[figure]{%
style=MarinoCaptionStyle
}


\begin{document}    
    
\begin{figure}
    \centering  
    \includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{example-image}
        \caption{A very nice centered caption}      
\end{figure}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: This sets the caption centred if it has multiple lines ([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqcxs.png)). The OP wants centred captions when they fit on a single line and justified captions when they fit on multiple lines ([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1iqjV.png)).